# How to specify maximum/minimum size for JavaFX Dialog

Tags: javafx, dialog, size, max, minimum-size

If my experience is representative then surprised this hasn't been asked before, I DID look.

I need to specify maximum and minimum size for a JFX Dialog, which does not have max/min/pref width/height properties .. BUT .. does have read only width and height properties together with standard get/set methods. I'm able to add an InvalidationListener to these properties, but nothing happens in the listener when I change the size by clicking and dragging on the dialog's edge. Tried using a ChangeListener, again nothing happens.

This is easy to test, just create a Dialog and basic listener and run System.out.println("dlg size changed") in listener implementation.

Lastly I tried the same with the dialog's DialogPane with same results.

Would be grateful to know if (i) what I'm attempting is possible, (ii) if so, then HOW, and (iii) if not, then why not?

Thanks!

Comment: are you setting resizable true?
After that a.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(x, y); seems to work for me :S

Comment: @el_chupacabra - thanks for replying, problem was a programming error. The technique described in the question works .. BUT .. it flickers. I tried what you suggested, it didn't work but you may be trying to do something different.

General question - should I drop this question (and if 'yes' then how?) and start a new one about the flicker?

Comment: I think you definitely should start a new question about that flicker issue, however I'm unsure about dropping this question, or if that is indeed possible by mere users. I'm fairly new to the registered community of stack overflow myself. Don't forget to post some code in that next question or you'll get flamed, **hard**.